# AudioKit v5-main Crash when Removing MIDI Listener

Tags: macos, midi, audiokit

I am building an app which listens to incoming MIDI using AudioKit v5.

I have an AudioKit MIDI shared instance in my AppDelegate and I have a class which conforms to MIDIListener.

The application is a Document Based application, and when the user closes the document, in order to release all references to my MIDIListener class instances, I need to remove each instance from the listeners array of my AudioKit MIDI shared instance. However, whenever I call `appDelegate.midi.removeListener(self)` from within my MIDIListener class instance, I experience a crash at the following line in the MIDIListener protocol:

```
func == (lhs: MIDIListener, rhs: MIDIListener) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqualTo(rhs)
}
```

Calling `appDelegate.midi.clearListeners()` does not cause a crash, but is unsuitable for me, as the user may have other open documents with MIDIListener instances which do not want to be removed from the shared instance Listeners array.

Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a bug with AudioKit MIDI implementation?